# How to use Gekko for trajectory optimization in discrete time

Tags: optimization, battery, gekko, discrete

I am trying to use Gekko to optimize (dis)charging of a battery energy storage system. Electricity prices per hour `EP`, energy production from solar panels `PV`, and energy demand `Dem` are considered over the entire horizon (0-24h) to minize total costs `TC`. Arbitrage should take place as the battery is (dis)charged (`Pbat_ch` & `Pbat_dis`) to/from the grid (`Pgrid_in` & `Pgrid_out`) at the optimal moments.

As opposed to most of the examples online, the problem is not formulated as a state-space model, but mostly relies on exogenous data for price, consumption and production. 3 specific issues with reference to Gurobi are outlined below, the entire code which results in the following error, can be found at the bottom of this post.

```
Exception:  @error: Inequality Definition
 invalid inequalities: z > x < y
 at0x0000016c6b214040>
 STOPPING . . .
```

1. The objective function is the sum of the costs resulting from buying/selling electricity to the grid over the entire horizon. I am used to Gurobi, which allows references to Manipulated Variables (`PowerGridOut` and `PowerGridIn = m.MV(...)`) at specific timesteps in this manner ([t]).

```
m.Obj(sum(ElectricityPrice[t]*PowerGridOut[t] - ElectricityPrice[t]*PowerGridIn[t]) for t in range(25))
```

Is this also possible in Gekko, or should this summation be recast as an integral? Is the following code correct?

```
ElectricityPrice = m.Param([..])
.
.
.
TotalCosts = m.integral(ElectricityPrice*(PowerGridOut - PowerGridIn))
m.Obj(TotalCosts)
m.options.IMODE = 6
m.solve()
```

2. Gurobi allows this formulation of the constraint to the change in state of charge of the battery:

```
m.addConstrs(SoC[t+1] == (SoC[t] - ((1/(DischargeEfficiency*BatteryCapacity)) * (PowerBattery
Discharge[t+1]) * Delta_t - ChargeEfficiency/BatteryCapacity * (PowerBatteryCharge[t+1]) * Delta_t)) for t in range(24))
```

Based on a question on stackoverflow regarding a similar problem, I have reformulated this in a continuous manner as:

```
m.Equation(SoC.dt() == SoC - 1/(DischargeEfficiency*BatteryCapacity) * Pbattdis - (ChargeEfficiency/BatteryCapacity) * Pbattch)
```

3. The final key constraint should the power balance, where `Demand[t]` & `PV[t]` are exogenous vectors, while the other variables are `m.MV()`:

```
m.Equation(((Demand[t] + Pbat_ch + Pgrid_in) == (PV[t] + Pgrid_out + Pbat_dis)) for t in range(25))
```

Unfortunately, all of this has not worked so far. I would highly appreciate it if someone could give me some hints. Ideally I would like to formulate both the objective function and constraints in discrete terms.

entire code

```
m       = GEKKO()
# horizon
m.time  = list(range(0,25))
# data vectors
EP      = m.Param(list(Eprice))
Dem     = m.Param(list(demand))
PV      = m.Param(list(production))
# constants
bat_cap = 13.5
ch_eff  = 0.94
dis_eff = 0.94
# manipulated variables
Pbat_ch = m.MV(lb=0, ub=4)
Pbat_ch.DCOST   = 0
Pbat_ch.STATUS  = 1
Pbat_dis = m.MV(lb=0, ub=4)
Pbat_dis.DCOST  = 0
Pbat_dis.STATUS = 1
Pgrid_in = m.MV(lb=0, ub=3)    
Pgrid_in.DCOST  = 0
Pgrid_in.STATUS = 1
Pgrid_out = m.MV(lb=0, ub=3) 
Pgrid_out.DCOST  = 0
Pgrid_out.STATUS = 1
#State of Charge Battery
SoC = m.Var(value=0.5, lb=0.2, ub=1)
#Battery Balance
m.Equation(SoC.dt() == SoC - 1/(dis_eff*bat_cap) * Pbat_dis - (ch_eff/bat_cap) * Pbat_ch)
#Energy Balance
m.Equation(((Dem[t] + Pbat_ch + Pgrid_in) == (PV[t] + Pbat_dis + Pgrid_out)) for t in range(0,25))
#Objective
TC = m.Var()
m.Equation(TC == sum(EP[t]*(Pgrid_out-Pgrid_in) for t in range(0,25)))
m.Obj(TC)
m.options.IMODE=6
m.options.NODES=3
m.options.SOLVER=3 
m.solve()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nice application! You can either write out all of your discrete equations yourself with `m.options.IMODE=3` or else let Gekko manage the time dimension for you. When you include an objective or constraint, it applies them to all of the time points that you specify. With `m.options.IMODE=6`, there is no need to add the set indices in Gekko such as `[t]`. Here is a simplified model:

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np

m       = GEKKO()
# horizon
m.time  = np.linspace(0,3,4)
# data vectors
EP      = m.Param([0.1,0.05,0.2,0.25])
Dem     = m.Param([10,12,9,8])
PV      = m.Param([10,11,8,10])
# constants
bat_cap = 13.5
ch_eff  = 0.94
dis_eff = 0.94
# manipulated variables
Pbat_ch = m.MV(lb=0, ub=4)
Pbat_ch.DCOST   = 0
Pbat_ch.STATUS  = 1
Pbat_dis = m.MV(lb=0, ub=4)
Pbat_dis.DCOST  = 0
Pbat_dis.STATUS = 1
Pgrid_in = m.MV(lb=0, ub=3)    
Pgrid_in.DCOST  = 0
Pgrid_in.STATUS = 1
Pgrid_out = m.MV(lb=0, ub=3) 
Pgrid_out.DCOST  = 0
Pgrid_out.STATUS = 1
#State of Charge Battery
SoC = m.Var(value=0.5, lb=0.2, ub=1)
#Battery Balance
m.Equation(bat_cap * SoC.dt() == -dis_eff*Pbat_dis + ch_eff*Pbat_ch)
#Energy Balance
m.Equation(Dem + Pbat_ch + Pgrid_in == PV + Pbat_dis + Pgrid_out)
#Objective
m.Minimize(EP*Pgrid_in)
# sell power at 90% of purchase (in) price
m.Maximize(0.9*EP*Pgrid_out)
m.options.IMODE=6
m.options.NODES=3
m.options.SOLVER=3 
m.solve()
```

I modified your differential equation to remove `SoC` from the right hand side, otherwise you'll get an exponential increase. The energy balance differential equation is `Accumulation=In-Out`. Here is some additional code to visualize the solution.

[image: Battery State of Charge]

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.subplot(3,1,1)
plt.plot(m.time,SoC.value,'b--',label='State of Charge')
plt.ylabel('SoC')
plt.legend()
plt.subplot(3,1,2)
plt.plot(m.time,Dem.value,'r--',label='Demand')
plt.plot(m.time,PV.value,'k:',label='PV Production')
plt.legend()
plt.subplot(3,1,3)
plt.plot(m.time,Pbat_ch.value,'g--',label='Battery Charge')
plt.plot(m.time,Pbat_dis.value,'r:',label='Battery Discharge')
plt.plot(m.time,Pgrid_in.value,'k--',label='Grid Power In')
plt.plot(m.time,Pgrid_in.value,':',color='orange',label='Grid Power Out')
plt.ylabel('Power')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Dear John, Thank you so much for your quick and elaborate feedback, it really addresses issues I couldn't have solved otherwise. If I may, I have one remaining problem: When applied to my measured PV and Dem data (wich are floats instead of integers), your model results in an error ("problem may be infeasible...error code is 2"). The solution seems only feasible if `sum(Dem) = sum(PV)`. However, this is by definition not the case: the model must ensure demand is met by supply, by changing `Pgrid_in`/`Pgrid_out`, `Pbat_ch`/`Pbat_dis` (of each pair, either one should by zero at each time).

Comment: I realize the follow up question above is somewhat different from the main question, so I have posted it as a new question using a different, more intuitive example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64033190/gekko-infeasible-solution-to-optimization-comparison-w-gurobi In any case many thanks again for the first answer!